# ¿Por qué mi proyecto sólo funciona bien en la API 25?

Tags: android, base-de-datos, api

tengo un problema de baja velocidad en dispositivos con APIs diferentes de la 25 y no sé cómo solucionarlo. Actualmente estoy realizando una aplicación que se conecta a una base de datos remota y lee datos desde un webservice y luego los muestra en la pantalla. Este es un ejemplo sencillo del menú principal de la aplicación:

```
public class PrincipalActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageView img_citas;
String cod_persona;
String nom;
String fecha_actual=String.valueOf(android.text.format.DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy", new java.util.Date()));


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal);


    img_citas = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_citas);

    cod_persona = 9;
    nom = "fisios";

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    ObtDatos();

}

public void ObtDatos(){

    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    String url = "http://192.168.0.252:62/datos/policlinica/webservices/nombre_fisio.php?COD_PERSONA="+cod_persona;


    client.post(url, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {

            if (statusCode==200){ 
                nom = obtCodigo(new String(responseBody)); 

                if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {     

                    if (!nom.equals("")) {  
                        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(nom);
                        getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle(fecha_actual);

                    } else {
                        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Policlínica");
                    }
                }

                img_citas.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        Intent i = new Intent(PrincipalActivity.this, HorariosActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                });
            }
        }


        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {

        }
    });

}

public String obtCodigo(String response){ 

    String cod_usu="";

    try{
        JSONArray json = new JSONArray(response);

        if (json.length()>0){   

            cod_usu = json.getJSONObject(0).getString("NOMBRE");
             }else{

            cod_usu="";
        }


    }catch (Exception e){
        e.getMessage();
    }

    return cod_usu;
}
}
```

Básicamente, lo único que hace es leer el nombre de una persona en una base de datos remota y colocarlo en el toolbar. Algo que no debería llevar más de 2 segundos, pero que a mi me tarda casi 9 segundos.

Por si acaso, adjunto también el contenido del archivo gradle, por si viniera por ahí el problema:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.cristobal.policlinica"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

El caso es que la aplicación funciona bien, pero sólo en dispositivos móviles con API 25 (Android 7). El resto, por ejemplo API 23 (Android 6) o API 28 (Android 8), aunque lee bien de la base de datos y los muestra, lo hace a muy baja velocidad. El código anterior, que es muy sencillo, tarda casi 9 segundos en leerlo completo y mostrarlo en pantalla. Mientras que con la API 25 es prácticamente instanténeo.

Seguro que se me escapa algo, pero creo que soy demasiado novato para verlo.

Edito:

Este es el LogCat de un dispositivo donde todo funciona bien:

```
06-14 09:43:25.837 6965-7103/com.example.cristobal.policlinica D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
06-14 09:43:26.333 6965-6976/com.example.cristobal.policlinica I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 4305(281KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(20KB) LOS objects, 0% free, 24MB/24MB, paused 7.051ms total 50.743ms
06-14 09:43:26.462 6965-6976/com.example.cristobal.policlinica I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 568(30KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 13% free, 24MB/28MB, paused 5.509ms total 117.376ms
06-14 09:43:27.303 6965-6972/com.example.cristobal.policlinica W/art: Suspending all threads took: 6.837ms
06-14 09:43:27.654 6965-6965/com.example.cristobal.policlinica V/AsyncHttpRH: Progress 72 from 72 (100%)
```

Y este es el LogCat de otro dispositivo donde va muy lento:

```
06-14 10:04:24.916 3086-3347/com.example.cristobal.policlinica D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
06-14 10:04:25.973 3086-3097/com.example.cristobal.policlinica W/art: Suspending all threads took: 95.884ms
06-14 10:04:26.009 3086-3093/com.example.cristobal.policlinica W/art: Suspending all threads took: 20.145ms
06-14 10:04:26.016 3086-3364/com.example.cristobal.policlinica W/art: Verification of java.lang.String cz.msebera.android.httpclient.protocol.DefaultedHttpContext.toString() took 143.593ms
06-14 10:04:26.016 3086-3097/com.example.cristobal.policlinica I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 5085(329KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(20KB) LOS objects, 29% free, 9MB/13MB, paused 106.940ms total 471.003ms
06-14 10:04:26.414 3086-3093/com.example.cristobal.policlinica W/art: Suspending all threads took: 11.969ms
06-14 10:04:31.861 3086-3086/com.example.cristobal.policlinica V/AsyncHttpRH: Progress 72 from 72 (100%)
```

Hay 3 líneas que son las que ralentizan la aplicación, aunque no entiendo muy bien el motivo. El caso es que los dos dispositivos son iguales, misma API (25) y Android 7.1. Lo único que cambia es el tamaño de la pantalla. No sé si va por ahí el asunto... aunque no lo termino de entender.

¿Algún consejo de lo que me está pasando?

Comment: Mimmetico, es importante revises el LogCat para determinar que sucede cuando se hace lenta tu aplicación.

Comment: Gracias Jorgesys, después de analizar varios LogCats veo que efectivamente hay algo que no va bien. Adjunto el código al hilo principal porque no termino de entender muy bien lo que está pasando.

Comment: Si quieres comunicarte con un servicio web te recomiendo que uses Retrofit ,te dejo un tutorial por aquí (http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Retrofit/article.html) ,al parecer tiene un problema de hilos,creo que se debe a la forma en la que estas cogiendo los datos con el AsyncHttpResponseHandler,lo que no se es porque en la api 25 te funciona bien

Comment: Muchas gracias, al final he seguido tu consejo y me he decidido por cambiar de librería. Al principio probé con Retrofit, pero todavía no le pillo el tranquillo, así que lo he hecho con Volley me funciona a la perfección sin apenas tocar nada.